# Determinant of dual basis inner products $\det[(e^i,e^j)_{V^{\ast}}]$

Tags: determinant, inner-products, exterior-algebra

$$\det[(e^i,e^j)_{V^{\ast}}]=(-1)^{N-S}$$

Where $S$ is the signature of the metric and dimensionality of underlying vector space is $\dim V=N$.
How is this equation holds/How is it derived? Does it work only for the Minkowski metric? Or this is true for any arbitrary metric?